# Sql query Group By

Tags: sql

I have a table '`OrderBook`'

it has field `Oid, symbol, price, qty, buysell`

i want to sum of `buy/sell` price and `Qty` group by `symbol`

Comment: @InSane: " `buy/sell` price" part is still not clear enough, since `price` is a field too.

Comment: @zerkms - Yup. I know. I can only format what i do understand :-) The OP will have to clarify that part

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT SUM(buy),
         SUM(sell),
         SUM(price),
         SUM(qty)
    FROM OrderBook
GROUP BY symbol
```

As you can see - SQL looks like natural language and is almost similar what you asked in the question ;-)

Comment: @rwilliams aka r-dub: actually i did not get his requirements well, but my answer should give a hint at least ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a 'stock trading order book'; the table probably contains individual orders made. The 'buy/sell' column indicates whether the trade was a purchase or a sale; and it is likely that the required statistics are the sum of 'price * quantity' (the value of the sales or purchases) and maybe sum of quantity too (total volume of shares), grouped by symbol and buy/sell status. I wonder if the OID somehow identifies the date and time of the order?

If this is correct, then the aggregation should probably be:

```
SELECT Symbol, BuySell,
       SUM(Price * Quantity) AS Value,
       SUM(Quantity) AS Volume
  FROM OrderBook
 GROUP BY Symbol, BuySell
 ORDER BY Symbol, BuySell;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT symbol,SUM(buy),SUM(sell),SUM(qty) FROM OrderBook 
GROUP BY symbol

use it this way, may the query could help u upto some extend...........
inside the SUM(table_field) write the field's name for which u want to get the sum.